# Replacing text inside span through CSS or JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to translate an app called Justuno into my own language. What I want to translate is the text on the social media buttons like "Share" and "Like", "Tweet" and "Follow". As in here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ClDb.png

Besides replacing the text I want to change the button titles, those little yellow boxes that open up when you hover over a link or button.

For instance the Facebook "Like" button code appears as this in Chrome developer tools:

```
<div class="pluginConnectButton">
    <div class="pluginButton pluginButtonSmall pluginButtonInline pluginConnectButtonDisconnected" **title="Like">**
        <div>
            <div class="pluginButtonContainer">
                <div class="pluginButtonImage">
                    <button type="submit">
<i class="pluginButtonIcon img sp_plugin-button sx_plugin-button_favblue"></i>

                    </button>
                </div>
<span class="pluginButtonLabel">**Like**</span>

            </div>
```

I want to change both the link/button title that appears when you hover over it, and the text that appears on buttons so when someone interacts with the pop they see the text in my own language rather than "Share" "Like" etc. The Justuno app admin panel offers two editing options, first one is iFrame CSS override and the second one is iFrame JS override. I should use one of these two, but I'm not sure which one and how to add the code exactly.

I'd be really glad if someone can help me with this.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to do this after the page has loaded using JavaScript? If so, take a look at [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.getElementsByClassName), etc. to select the elements you're interested in and modify their attributes. Have you tried anything already? If so, are you experiencing any specific problems?

Comment: No, I don't want the change to be after the page has loaded and to be honest I don't have a clue about how to modify the elements through the method you've mentioned. I'm very unfamiliar with any kind of coding, the most I can manage to do is change the font size and family through pasting some css code i found in chrome developer tools to the css editor. I also don't know how to implement the codes that are suggested below, should I just copy and paste them to the CSS or JS editor? (I'm really sorry if these questions sound stupid, I'm trying to manage something way beyond my abilities).

Comment: Any of the JS- or jQuery-based solutions posted below are modifying the page after it has loaded. You can try running them in the JS console but to be honest, you shouldn't be blindly copying code that you don't understand. It's not clear what you're trying to do; can't you just change the HTML? Please update your question to provide more details about your situation.

Comment: Ok, I think I've made it more clear

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery like this

```
$(".pluginConnectButton").find(".pluginConnectButtonDisconnected").attr("title","mytitle");
$(".pluginConnectButton").find(".pluginButtonLabel").html("mytitle");
```

Comment: But I think content from other sites in iframe does not allow too change sometime using jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('span.pluginButtonLabel').text('my text');
    // end put here same for each span you need
})
```

here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q8bo9oL4/).

Same functionality using plain JavaScript:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("pluginButtonLabel")[0].innerHTML = "my text";
```

Comment: @TomFenech, you are right. I thought it doesn't matter in this case. By the way I have updated my answer

Comment: Thanks! But how can I implement this exactly? I've changed my post a little bit, could you please check it again?

Comment: As far as I understand there are exist frame for each button. In this case you can't change anything in frame which was loaded from another site (domain). Security features built into all browsers ensure that Javascript cannot interact with objects in other windows and/or frames if those Windows or frames were loaded from a different site. Whether something was loaded from a different site is determined by the hostname part of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to mention that the HTML you have shown is actually inside an `<iframe>`. This means that you cannot directly change the elements (from the console, for example). Looking at [this article](http://support.justuno.com/support/articles/4000024752-passing-data-back-and-forth-between-justuno-and-your), it seems like you can define the function `ju_callback` in your JS override, which can be used to modify the HTML.

To change the title attribute of the div from "old title" to "new title", you could use something like the following:

```
function ju_callback() {
    var i, e, title, 
        elements = document.getElementsByClassName("pluginButton pluginButtonSmall pluginButtonInline pluginConnectButtonDisconnected");

    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
        e = elements[i];
        if (e.getAttribute("title") === "old title") {
            e.setAttribute("title", "new title");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Tom! I will definitely try this and let you know if it works.

Answer (score -1):

you can only do this using javaScript. for example:

`var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
spans[0].textContent = "translated text"; // for the first element from spans`

Comment: Typo aside, it's not a very good approach to assume that there will always be a given number of `<span>` elements on the page and that this one will always be the first one.

Comment: @TomFenech, I've just wanted to give an example, so that he could get an idea. Otherwise, I would have to create a collection of translations, which would be, imo, an excessive information.